# How to show all of the errors with JSHint

Tags: jshint

Say I run JSHint on a file. It reports back 83% of the errors. I want 100% of the errors, but by default it says "Too many errors". Running `jshint filename.js`, how would I lift this limit and show all of the errors?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

see this issue : https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/180

from there :

> /*jshint maxerr: 10000 */

Comment: This is the best answer (as of version 2.1.9); much better than modifying the JSHint sources. JSHint will accept `maxerr:9999` as a standard option, even though it doesn't appear to be documented.

Comment: You can also do this via `.jshintrc` file

Answer (score 11):

By default, JSHint will produce 50 warnings before giving up. 
Unfortunately, there is not an option to turn that off completely. The reason is because on large scripts JSHint would be too slow.

If you want to increase the amount of warnings that JSHint will produce, 
just edit file **.jshintrc** and add the option:

```json
{
    "maxerr" : 999
}
```

Answer (score -4):

- Go to `~/.node_modules/jshint/packages/jshint`
  (on Windows go to `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data\npm\node_modules\jshint\packages\jshint`)
- Open `jshint.js` file.
- Go to the line 1065 and delete this if statement:

```
if (warnings >= option.maxerr) {
    quit("Too many errors.", l, ch);`
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this. It's generally not a good idea to edit packages directly. If you must do it, fork it, create your own "version" that has this and then install it

Comment: @nobody This is not the right way to make something work... Suggestion from Shamoon is good.